# How to connect 3 UIButton to one outlet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutletcollection

I try to do something like this @IBoutlet var buttons : [UIButton]

but I can't drag button to this outlet

Any idea, how can I achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564249/can-i-connect-multiple-objects-with-different-tags-to-the-same-iboutlet

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to do that.

Here is how:

- Create an array of IBOutlets
- Add multiple UIElements (Views) in your Storyboard ViewController interface
- Select ViewController (In storyboard) and open connection inspector
- There is option 'Outlet Collections' in connection inspector (You will see an array of outlets there)
- Connect if with your interface elements

-

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var collection:[UIView]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add a button to an existing array outlet, drag the other way 'round: from the circle in the margin of the view controller to the button. (No need to hold the control key while doing this drag.)